# How to use delay time value for "on exit" in delay object?

Tags: anylogic

I am looking to code my *"on exit"* box in my delay object to multiply by the delay time. I had the delay time set to 75 so I had it coded,

```
Total_Cost += 75*(Direct_Cost);
```

But I have now changed my delay time to triangular distribution of:

```
triangular (70, 80, 75);
```

Answer (score 0):

first don't use Total_Cost =+ but instead Total_Cost +=

second you can just do

```
Total_Cost += time()-agent.getBlockEnterTime()
```

this will take whatever delay time was used, no matter what you use.

Comment: So will my Total_Cost value be as follows: Total_Cost += (time()-agent.getBlockEnterTime())*(Direct_Cost);  ?